# is any concept of hard float and soft float exist in case of armv4t processor family?

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling, toolchain, arm9

which toolchain i have to use for building a source code for arm 9 processor family (armv4t ) . i have used `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -marm -march=armv4t` for building of my source code , but this does not work .

And can anyone tell me about origin of the hard float or soft float os concept .
is this concept comes in arm 9 processor family or come later .

Comment: You have to be explicit, `but this does not work` not gives any informaton

Comment: @user1034749 what do you mean ?

Comment: I mean do get answer you have to provide details. Not `this does not work`, but something like compiler print `Error: unsupported instruction vldr`. And not ask about history of concept, but something like should I use hard/soft float for CPU at91sam9263

Comment: @user1034749 when i build my code for arm9 using toolchain available on given link [https://launchpad.net/~kayo-k11-4/+archive/ubuntu/dev-tools/+build/2892260] . when i run the sample using static library it runs but when i run using dynamic library it through an error i.e no library found (i have already set LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable ) .